# Rounding a number in java doesn't seem to work the way it should

Tags: java, methods, rounding

my code:

```
static int klassenBreite(int histMin, int histMax, int klassen) {
    int abstand =(int) ((histMax- histMin)/klassen +0.5);

    return abstand;
}
```

if I run

```
klassenBreite(100,200,8);
```

I should get 13, but my program calculates it to be 12. I really don't know what went wrong, if I do it by hand it gives 13. I am not sure if I'm rounding it correctly.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with klassenBreite, but is that integer division intentional? Because my guess is it's not...

Comment: Do you know what `int` stands for?

Comment: it's a method i have created myself

Comment: I still haven't got an answer on my question, why would you mark it as a duplicate when it's not at all a duplicate? @kayaman

Comment: Well, I see integer division -> I close it as integer division. I see `NullPointerException`, I close it as "What is a NPE and how do I fix it". So is that integer division in your code intentional?

Comment: yes, but I don't understand why it gives back 12 when it should return 13. I add 0.5, which would give 13... Where do you see a NullPointerException? thanks!

Comment: Are you **really** sure that **integer** division is intentional? The concept which is discussed in detail in the duplicate?

Comment: @Cherry It is blatantly a duplicate. Read it.

Comment: I have read it. I have a question: if I add a double to an integer, do I get a double or and integer?

Comment: btw it worked when I converted one to double but I don't understand why

Comment: Because integer division gives you an integer result, so `(200-100)/8` is `12`. Add `0.5`, cast to int and you still have `12`. Next time **read** the duplicate before saying "it's not a duplicate".